# Huge Block Time in Profiler in Azure App Service Response

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

My Web App is running on Basic 2 Tier in Azure. But from past few days I'm Getting **Huge Block Time** when seen in the profiler. So, Is anyone having any idea about there is so much block Time in request processing.

[Profiler Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoI8e.png)

Comment: Just a guess, it might be that the server is too slow because of CPU/memory/IO bottleneck.

Comment: Since no one answers this question, I submit a ticket at app insights home at git hub, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/309).

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-performance see if it helps to identify the issue.